# Make div appear in current user screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a "mini-slider" which works fine. I'd like to let users click on any image and make a div tag which holds another slider appear ( it occupies almost the whole screen ). I have already tried to put it with display: none and change to block when clicking any image, but I have these problems:

- I don't know how to position it so that it appears in the center of the user's current screen
- I don't know how to use z-index so that it appears over all the other elements

Any idea would be great, thanks!

Comment: please put code that you have tried so far

Comment: You can set `position: absolute` and `z-index: [some high number]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are searching for is probably very close to this  https://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

The Light box idea is simply to add a layer above your current layer of code , kinda like a pop up , hope this helps !

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I didn't know there were already built examples though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood this is what you need [Image slider lightbox](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp)